# LINQ Join to get latest record from 2nd table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Problem:

Their are two tables TableEmails and TableSentEmailRecords. So when ever emails are sent out, a records, such as sent time etc are stored in TableSentEmailRecords.

I want to do a LINQ query, which gets me columns of TableEmails PLUS a "SentDate" column from TableSentEmailRecords that displays the latest date that email was sent out.

I tried this:

```
List<CustomEmail> emails = new List<CustomEmail>();

var query = from c in db.TableEmails 
            join o in db.TableSentEmailRecords on c.EmailId equals o.EmailId
                        select new CustomEmail
                        {
                            EmailName = c.EmailName,
                            EmailId= c.EmailId,
                            EmailDescription = c.EmailDescription,
                            LastDateEmailSentOut = o.SentDate
                        };

emails = query.ToList();
```

but this not necessarily get the latest record of that particular email from TableSentEmailRecords  table.

Any Ideas ???

Answer (score 5):

You could just use a nested query instead of the join:

```
var query = from c in db.TableEmails 
            select new CustomEmail
            {
                EmailName = c.EmailName,
                EmailId= c.EmailId,
                EmailDescription= c.EmailDescription,
                LastDateEmailSentOut = db.TableSentEmailRecordson
                                         .Where(x => x.EmailId = c.EmailId)
                                         .Max(x => x.SentDate)
            };
```

Comment: thanks ... looks like this may work ... just a another point (sorry i forgot to mention in question) ... the same (Max) record whose Date I will be using as LastDateEmailSentOut, i want to use that records other values to populate few other properties in my query. Can i do that?

Comment: @aDev I have added details about this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think GroupJoin is the correct method in this case. Using a sub query will work but it is not going to be as efficient. Sorry, I don't know the simpler query syntax that well and especially I don't know how to do group join with it. Maybe someone can translate.

```
db.TableEmails.GroupJoin(db.TableSendEmailRecordson,
  o => o.EmailID,
  i => i.EmailID,
  (o, i) => new
  {
    EmailName = c.EmailName,
    EmailId= c.EmailId,
    EmailDescription= c.EmailDescription,
    LastDateEmailSentOut = i.Max(x => x.SentDate)
  })
```

To get all the details from TableSendEmailRecordson you could do something like this:

```
db.TableEmails.GroupJoin(db.TableSendEmailRecordson,
  o => o.EmailID,
  i => i.EmailID,
  (o, i) => new
  {
    EmailName = c.EmailName,
    EmailId= c.EmailId,
    EmailDescription = c.EmailDescription,
    LastSendEmailRecordson = i.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SentDate == i.Max(x => x.SentDate))
  })
```

That may complain about being translated to SQL, if that is the case then you need to first get the data and then use the results in the query, eg

```
var emails = db.TableEmails.ToArray();
var emailSend = db.TableSendEmailRecordson.ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this:

```
var query = (from c in db.TableEmails 
            join o in db.TableSentEmailRecordson c.EmailId equals o.EmailId
            select new CustomEmail
            {
                EmailName = c.EmailName,
                EmailId = c.EmailId,
                EmailDescription = c.EmailDescription,
                LastDateEmailSentOut = o.SentDate
            }).OrderByDescending(c => c.LastDateEmailSentOut).ToList();
```